# Import from sql server to hbase, retrieved 395809 records from sql using sqoop, but only 365587 rows in hbase

Tags: sql-server, import, hbase, sqoop

Import data from sql server to hbase,  retrieved 395809 records from sql using sqoop, but only 365587 rows in hbase.

The import command I used is

```html
 sqoop import --hbase-table test --hbase-row-key conversation_id --column-family cf1 --columns conversation_id,app_id --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://******;database=*******;username=test;password=*******" --table test -m 1
```

The command I used to create Hbase table is

```html
 create 'test',{NAME=>'cf1',BLOCKCACHE=> false,BLOCKSIZE=>1073741824}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks,

Mqi

Comment: Is conversation_id unique?

Comment: I just check, there is some duplicate of those records. Thanks @ Sachin Janani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to say, but chances are `conversation_id` is not unique. For more interactive help on this subject, try the [sqoop mailing lists](http://sqoop.apache.org/mail-lists.html).

Comment: Yes, I just found the records are duplicate. Thanks